# How to Give Sequential Names to DataFrames Using Loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I've succeed on splitting a `DataFrame` into several smaller `DataFrames`. I'm now working on giving these `DataFrames` sequential names, and can be called independently.

```
shuffled = df.sample(frac=1)
result = np.array_split(shuffled, 3) 

for part in result:
    print(part, '\n')

movie_id  1  2  5  borda  rank  IRAM
2         3  4  0  0      4     3     2
1         2  3  0  3      6     2     1 

   movie_id  1  2  5  borda  rank  IRAM
4         5  3  0  0      3     4     3
0         1  5  4  4     13     1     4 

   movie_id  1  2  5  borda  rank  IRAM
3         4  3  0  0      3     4     3
```

I want to give names in sequential order to these separated `DataFrames` with loop(or any helpful methods).

For instance :

```
df_1
   movie_id  1  2  5  borda  rank  IRAM
2         3  4  0  0      4     3     2
1         2  3  0  3      6     2     1 

df_2
   movie_id  1  2  5  borda  rank  IRAM
4         5  3  0  0      3     4     3
0         1  5  4  4     13     1     4 

df_3
   movie_id  1  2  5  borda  rank  IRAM
3         4  3  0  0      3     4     3
```

I've been searching solutions for a while, but I can't find an ideally answer to my problem.

Comment: exactly this was included in my answer if you see your previous question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by taking a dictionary and adding all dataframes into it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': np.random.randint(10, size=10)})
shuffled = df.sample(frac=1)
result = np.array_split(shuffled, 3) 
d = {}
for i, part in enumerate(result):
    d['df_'+str(i)] = part          # If want to start the number for df from 1 then use str(i+1)

print(d['df_0'])
   Col1
7     7
6     0
4     5
2     3

print(d['df_1'])
   Col1
0     0
8     1
1     5

print(d['df_2'])
   Col1
5     2
3     2
9     4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df_dict = {}
for index, splited in enumerate(result):
    df_name = "df_{}".format(index)
    # if you want to set name of the dataframe
    splited.name = df_name
    # if you want to set the variable name to dataframe
    df_dict[df_name] = splited
print(df_dict)
```

```
{'df_0':    movie_id  1  2  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  borda
 9        10  3  2  0  0  0  4  0  0   0   0   0      9
 7         8  1  0  0  0  4  5  0  0   0   4   0     14
 6         7  4  0  0  0  2  5  3  4   4   0   0     22
 0         1  5  4  0  4  4  0  0  0   4   0   0     21,
 'df_1':    movie_id  1  2  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  borda
 8         9  5  0  0  0  4  5  0  0   4   5   0     23
 3         4  3  0  0  0  0  5  0  0   4   0   5     17
 5         6  5  0  0  0  0  0  0  5   0   0   0     10,
 'df_2':    movie_id  1  2  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  borda
 4         5  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0      3
 2         3  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0      4
 1         2  3  0  0  3  0  0  0  0   0   0   0      6}
```

Then you can call any `splited_df` by `df_dict[df_name]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary, like this:

```
d = {"df_"+str(k):v for (k,v) in [(i,result[i]) for i in range(len(result))]}
```